# Python `TemporaryDirectory` release on interpreter shutdown

Tags: python, temporary-files, finalizer

I am using [`tempfile.TemporaryDirectory`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory). I need a directory which lives as long as my program. I do however run into some issues when the interpreter is shutting down.

Consider the mock example:

```py
import tempfile
import typing
import sys

class Foo:
   tempDir: tempfile.TemporaryDirectory
   file: typing.io

   def __del__():
      sys.stderr.write(''.join(['in finalizer ', self.tempDir.name, '\n']))
      self.file.close()
      self.tempDir.cleanUp()
      sys.stderr.write('finalizer done\n')
```

`TemporaryDirectory` automatically registers a finalizer to remove the temporary directory from disk. I does so by using [`weakref.finalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.finalize). When the interpreter shuts down, I occasionally see that the two finalizer operations to be out of order: `tempDir`'s finalizer is called *before* my `__del__()` method above. In my finalizer, I still have  a perfectly good reference to the `TemporaryDirectory`.

This is the error messages I see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\welterp\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\qs3\lib\weakref.py", line 624, in _exitfunc
    f()
  File "C:\Users\welterp\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\qs3\lib\weakref.py", line 548, in __call__
    return info.func(*info.args, **(info.kwargs or {}))
  File "C:\Users\welterp\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\qs3\lib\tempfile.py", line 799, in _cleanup
    _shutil.rmtree(name)
  File "C:\Users\welterp\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\qs3\lib\shutil.py", line 494, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\welterp\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\qs3\lib\shutil.py", line 389, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\welterp\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\qs3\lib\shutil.py", line 387, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\welterp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpd6ps3rj6\\scalarData.h5'
in finalizer C:\Users\welterp\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpd6ps3rj6
finalizer done
```

Clearly the interpreter triggers the weakref finalizer before mine!

Makes no sense to me.

Comment: I do have a hunch about where to look: the weakref finalizer is guaranteed to run in an early stage where [alll the globals are still valid](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/weakref.html#weakref.finalize). This is not guaranteed for the `__del__` finalizer. So is it possible that the finalizer of an object is called even when there still is a reference to it?!